# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to build a countdown timer in xcode but for some reason it does not work.

I have tried all kinds of methonds but I still keep getting the same error.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        // text field counter
    var count:Int = 300

    @IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    }
    @objc func countDown(){
        counter.text = String(count)
        count -= 1


    }


}
```

This is the error that I got:

> -[__SwiftValue countDown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000025dde00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an instance method in the initialization of the instance member without using `lazy` computed initialization so it is not guaranteed you will get completely initialized instance to bind its method. Schedule `timer` as below,

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    // text field counter
    var count:Int = 300

    @IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!
    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func countDown(){
        counter.text = String(count)
        count -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked!!! Finally get it now, really thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just check if 
@IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!
is connected to your storyboard label
[image]

Comment: This is the answer to my problem!